# Solve An expression of non-boolean type specified on trigger which check latitude and longitude

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to create a trigger which check latitude and longitude but I can't add this trigger because I have error

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Procedure t_point_between, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 0]
> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

My trigger looks that

```
create trigger t_point_between
on Vehicle
after insert 
as
begin
    declare @latitude as float  
    declare @longitude as float 

    if (select latitude from Vehicle  v where v.latitude)< 19.7922354 and latitude > 20.2173455
    begin
        print 'Incorrect latitude!!!'
        print 'latitude must be between 19.7922354 and 20.2173455'
    end
    
    if (select longitude from Vehicle where longitude)< 49.9676667 and longitude > 50.1261338
    begin
        print 'Incorrect longitude!!!'
        print 'longitude must be between 49.9676667 and 50.1261338'
    end     
end
go
```

Trigger after insert check the latitude and longitude which must be from this points when latitude is not from this points print the massage.

Why I have this issue? Can someone explain why?

Comment: Why does your trigger not reference `inserted` at all? What are the variables `@latitude` and `@longitude` for when they aren't used?

Comment: Also, it looks like you're trying to reference columns from your sub queries outside of them? That won't work.

Comment: As for the error, you have the clause `where v.latitude)` (and `where longitude)`). Where the value of `latitude` is *what*? That's only half a boolean expression, hence the error.

Comment: Finally, why are you doing this as a `TRIGGER`, and why does said `TRIGGER` not stop the transaction by `THROW`ing? A `CHECK CONSTRAINT` would be infinitely superior to a `TRIGGER`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `TRIGGER` at all, use a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Vehicle
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_VehicleLocale CHECK (latitude >= 19.7922354
                                    AND latitude <= 20.2173455
                                    AND longitude >= 49.9676667
                                    AND longitude <= 50.1261338);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is what you want.

- You need to reference the `Inserted` pseudo-table to test the current insert.
- You need to use `OR` rather than `AND` to test for a value outside the range
- You need to use `EXISTS` to test if a bad value exists.
- You need to pull the entire condition inside the sub-query

```
create trigger t_point_between
on Vehicle
after insert 
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    if exists (select 1 from Inserted v where v.latitude < 19.7922354 or v.latitude > 20.2173455)
    begin
        print 'Incorrect latitude!!!';
        print 'latitude must be between 19.7922354 and 20.2173455';
    end;
    
    if exists (select 1 from Inserted v where v.longitude < 49.9676667 or v.longitude > 50.1261338)
    begin
        print 'Incorrect longitude!!!';
        print 'longitude must be between 49.9676667 and 50.1261338';
    end;
end;
go
```

Note, printing this error in a normal client context won't do much. You probably want to `THROW` an error.